# Recording multi-channel audio input in real-time

Tags: real-time, signal-processing, recording, audacity

I am trying to perform Time Difference of Arrival in real-time using the PS3 Eye. Since it has a built-in 4 microphone array, I've successfully rearranged the array into a square array and cross-correlated the signals using MATLAB to obtain a relatively accurate TDOA algorithm. However, so far I've been recording the signal, saving the files (4 individual files for each microphone in the array), and then feeding those files into MATLAB to read after-the-fact.

My problem is: MATLAB doesn't recognize the PS3 Eye's microphones separately; it only recognizes it as a whole. So far, Audacity is one of the few programs that actually works well in doing so, but I am inexperienced in using the program and don't know its real-time capabilities. Anyone have suggestions as to how can I can perform real-time signal analysis in this manner? If using something else besides the PS3 Eye would work better, then I am open to suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, so what two times are you correlating? The basic here is: If the PS3 Eye has only "one cable" you cannot have each mic separately. So if this is the case, the output signal of the mic would be mono/one channel, contrary to what @AndrewCharneski says.

Comment: What system are you reading data in on? I am assuming windows. Because of this, it limits you but if you could tell us how you connected the channels I might be able to help you out with a device mapping script. Then you can record it as multi-channel audio using any program you like.

Comment: Basically I do not understand the question: You say you HAVE 4 files per mic in the array, but MATLAB does not recognize the 4 mics, do you want to "record" directly to MATLAB? "but I am inexperienced in using the program and don't know its real-time capabilities", do you mean Audacity with that? If Audacity gives you the ability to record 4 files per mic (what would that be?), you also can map the output of Audacity while "recording" (on pause) to MATLAB, or does MATLAB itself not have the ability to listen to several channels? (I do not know, I am just somebody with 20 years in music biz.)

Answer (score 0):

I know very little about MATLAB or PS3 eye, but various hardware microphones allow you to capture a single audio stream containing multiple (typically 2) channels. The audio data will come to you in frames, each frame containing a single sample for each channel.

I'm not really sure what you mean by "recognizes as a whole", but I assume you mean MATLAB is mixing the channels so that the device only produces one usable channel. If you can capture the channels to file, and they all originate from the same device (i.e. hardware clock), you should be fine except that this solution is not "realtime".

There is a similar discussion on [Sound Exchange](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/23849/monitoring-multiple-usb-microphones) which ends up suggesting the [Microcone](http://www.dev-audio.com/products/microcone/). There are a variety of other products, from microphone arrays to digital mixers for analog mic sources, also, but your question seems to be mainly about how to get the data with software.

In short, make sure you are seeing a single device with multiple channels. This will ensure each channel uses the same hardware clock and will prevent drift issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild guess as I don't know know about MATLAB real time input options.

Maybe try reaper ( http://www.reaper.fm/ ).. it has great multi track capabilities and you can extend it (I think the scripting language is python ). Nice documentation and third party contributions, OSC and Rewire support. So maybe you could think of routing the audio to reaper, doing some data normalization there in python and then route data to MATLAB.

Or you could use PURE DATA which is open source and very open, with lots of patches (basic processing units) that you could probably put together.

HTH

BTW I am in no way affiliated wit reaper or PD.

EDIT: you might also want to consider supercollider (http://supercollider.github.io/) or Chuck (http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a lead, but I haven't been able to test it, yet.

On Windows, you can record a single 4 track ogg audio file from the Eye with Audacity (using the WASAPI driver selection).

As of 23 Jul 2014, the [pa-wavplay for 32-bit and 64-bit](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47336-pa-wavplay-for-32-bit-and-64-bit?s_tid=srchtitle) MEX supports WASAPI. You will have to rebuild the PortAudio library to select the WASAPI interface as described [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102950-how-do-i-use-asio-alsa-and-other-apis-to-communicate-with-pc-audio-hardware-from-simulink?s_tid=srchtitle) and get all four tracks in MatLab (in Windows).

Sadly, if you're not on Windows, I don't have any suggestions. Adjusting the PortAudio build might help, but I only know that WASAPI works with the Eye.